# SharePoint 2013 - Add a User to The UserInformationList

Tags: post, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, user-information-list

I'm currently having a little problem and I'm not quite sure how to solve it yet. The situation is this. In SharePoint 2013 I'm using the REST-API to update and create List Items.

If there is a ppl-Picker the Values are the Ids of the users in the UserInformationList. So far so good. But now heres my question.

This does not work with users that are not in the UserInformationList yet. SharePoint in nativc somehow seems to make to POST-Requests when I'm searching for a user that does not exist yet. The first one seems to fetch users from another list given the string entered so far in the ppl picker. That body looks like this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="15.0.0.0" ApplicationName="Javascript Library">
   <Actions>
      <StaticMethod TypeId="{xxxxxxxxxxxxx}" Name="ClientPeoplePickerSearchUser" Id="5">
         <Parameters>
            <Parameter TypeId="{xxxxxxxxxxxxx}">
               <Property Name="AllowEmailAddresses" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
               <Property Name="AllowMultipleEntities" Type="Boolean">true</Property>
               <Property Name="AllUrlZones" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
               <Property Name="EnabledClaimProviders" Type="String" />
               <Property Name="ForceClaims" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
               <Property Name="MaximumEntitySuggestions" Type="Number">30</Property>
               <Property Name="PrincipalSource" Type="Number">15</Property>
               <Property Name="PrincipalType" Type="Number">1</Property>
               <Property Name="QueryString" Type="String">jack</Property>
               <Property Name="Required" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
               <Property Name="SharePointGroupID" Type="Number">0</Property>
               <Property Name="UrlZone" Type="Number">0</Property>
               <Property Name="UrlZoneSpecified" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
               <Property Name="Web" Type="Null" />
               <Property Name="WebApplicationID" Type="String">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Property>
            </Parameter>
         </Parameters>
      </StaticMethod>
   </Actions>
   <ObjectPaths />
</Request>
```

It then gets back a JSON with the user Information. When I now send the form a second POST-Request is made basically containing all the form-info looking somewhat like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="15.0.0.0" ApplicationName="Javascript Library">
   <Actions>
      <ObjectPath Id="3" ObjectPathId="2" />
      <ObjectPath Id="5" ObjectPathId="4" />
      <ObjectPath Id="7" ObjectPathId="6" />
      <ObjectPath Id="9" ObjectPathId="8" />
      <ObjectPath Id="11" ObjectPathId="10" />
      <ExceptionHandlingScopeSimple Id="12">
         <Method Name="ValidateUpdateListItem" Id="14" ObjectPathId="10">
            <Parameters>
               <Parameter Type="Array">
                  <Object TypeId="{xxxxxxxxxxx}">
                     <Property Name="ErrorMessage" Type="Null" />
                     <Property Name="FieldName" Type="String">Title</Property>
                     <Property Name="FieldValue" Type="String">___test</Property>
                     <Property Name="HasException" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
                  </Object>
                  <Object TypeId="{xxxxxxxxxxx}">
                     <Property Name="ErrorMessage" Type="Null" />
                     <Property Name="FieldName" Type="String">Someone</Property>
                     <Property Name="FieldValue" Type="String" />
                     <Property Name="HasException" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
                  </Object>
                  <Object TypeId="{xxxxxxxxxxx}">
                     <Property Name="ErrorMessage" Type="Null" />
                     <Property Name="FieldName" Type="String">LookupField</Property>
                     <Property Name="FieldValue" Type="String" />
                     <Property Name="HasException" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
                  </Object>
                  <Object TypeId="{xxxxxxxxxxx}">
                     <Property Name="ErrorMessage" Type="Null" />
                     <Property Name="FieldName" Type="String">SomeTextField</Property>
                     <Property Name="FieldValue" Type="String" />
                     <Property Name="HasException" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
                  </Object>
                  <Object TypeId="{xxxxxxxxxxx}">
                     <Property Name="ErrorMessage" Type="Null" />
                     <Property Name="FieldName" Type="String">APerson</Property>
                     <Property Name="FieldValue" Type="String">[{"Key":"i:0#.w|dom\\xxxxxx","Description":"DOM\\xxxxx","DisplayText":"Some, Name","EntityType":"User","ProviderDisplayName":"Active Directory","ProviderName":"AD","IsResolved":true,"EntityData":{"Title":"","MobilePhone":"","SIPAddress":"some.person@mail.com","Department":"XX-XX","Email":"some.person@mail.com"},"MultipleMatches":[],"AutoFillKey":"i:0#.w|dom\\xxxxxxx","AutoFillDisplayText":"Person, Some","AutoFillSubDisplayText":"","AutoFillTitleText":"SomeString","DomainText":"some.domain.net","Resolved":true,"LocalSearchTerm":"some"}]</Property>
                     <Property Name="HasException" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
                  </Object>
                  <Object TypeId="{xxxxxxxxxxx}">
                     <Property Name="ErrorMessage" Type="Null" />
                     <Property Name="FieldName" Type="String">ContentType</Property>
                     <Property Name="FieldValue" Type="String">Element</Property>
                     <Property Name="HasException" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
                  </Object>
                  <Object TypeId="{xxxxxxxxxxx}">
                     <Property Name="ErrorMessage" Type="Null" />
                     <Property Name="FieldName" Type="String">ContentTypeId</Property>
                     <Property Name="FieldValue" Type="String">0x010020785F18D738D74797A0C6B07438E69E</Property>
                     <Property Name="HasException" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
                  </Object>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter Type="Boolean">false</Parameter>
               <Parameter Type="Null" />
            </Parameters>
         </Method>
      </ExceptionHandlingScopeSimple>
   </Actions>
   <ObjectPaths>
      <StaticProperty Id="2" TypeId="{xxxxxxxxxxx}" Name="Current" />
      <Property Id="4" ParentId="2" Name="Web" />
      <Property Id="6" ParentId="4" Name="Lists" />
      <Method Id="8" ParentId="6" Name="GetById">
         <Parameters>
            <Parameter Type="String">xxxxxxxxxxx</Parameter>
         </Parameters>
      </Method>
      <Method Id="10" ParentId="8" Name="AddItem">
         <Parameters>
            <Parameter TypeId="{xxxxxxxxxxx}">
               <Property Name="FolderUrl" Type="String">/sites/site/lists/theList</Property>
               <Property Name="LeafName" Type="Null" />
               <Property Name="UnderlyingObjectType" Type="Number">0</Property>
            </Parameter>
         </Parameters>
      </Method>
   </ObjectPaths>
</Request>
```

This second post also somehow seems to create the user in the UserInformationList. So my question is.

Is there a way to create the users that are not existant in the UserInformationList yet and get back their Ids after they are created?

As I only developed SharePoint on the front-end I'm not too familiar with its architecture. Would be great if someone of you guys could help me out here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [EnsureUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx#bk_WebEnsureUser) method on the web which will create the user, if it does not exist, and return its ID.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to work on that and get back to how it went ;)

Comment: One thing that would still be open. From the People-Picker I only get back the UserLogin. With EnsureUser I can create a new User, but still one problem is, that I dont have the rest of its information like department, Tilte etc. Is there also a part in this API to get that stuff? I guess i somehow have to mimic the first POST-request, but with the login to get a unique answer. I just would prefer a /web/_api method over trying to rebuild that request with a xml-body where I'm not sure what half of the input means

Comment: It seems that once a user is added to the ppl picker, they are in the Active Directory. So I guess now I have to find a way to get the Users Information from the Active Directory with the given LoginName

Comment: If you need some other information about the user you can get them from his profile using [GetPropertiesFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx#bk_PeopleManagerGetPropertiesFor).

Comment: Ok the getProperties worked. I just had to use the GetMyProperties first because the AccountName isn't the LoginName but formatted differently. Unfortunately i can't get the JSON-Data in the EnsureUser right. I tried

'logonName': 'i:0#.f|membership|user@domain.onmicrosoft.com' 

with now luck. Tried it with the account name and all kinds of combination. sill no luck. Any idea what else should be submitted with the POST?

Comment: Ok figured out I only needed the LoginName, no AccountName or additional Information. All I did wrong was something with the stringified JSON. So for all that go through these comments. For EnsureUser you will just need the LoginName and use that for logonName in the Link Lukas provided. Thanks again